# Magento 2, cannot use all option attributes when creating new configuration product

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.2, product-attribute

Using Magento 2.2, Back-end, Catalog-Product. I **cannot use all product attributes** for a new configuration product. Why can't I use all attributes in **Stores -> Configuration**?

New Product

> **Catalog-Product -> New Configuration Product**
>   [image]

Attribute List

> **Stores -> Product Attributes**
>   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per as Magento, you can use those attributes for configurable attribute creation whose  **Scope** is **Global** and attribute type is **dropdown** and also enable for Configurable.

[image]
**In your shared screens Color,size, format matches with that conditions.**

Comment: So mean that I cannot use **Multiple Select** + **Global** for **Configurable product**?

Comment: Not multi Select.Dropdown with Global

Comment: Okay, I understand.

Comment: Have any solution for enable Multiple Select + Global for Configurable product?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any solution for multi select